# Focusing on an input field clips the modal background

Tags: css

CSS is acting up. I have a modal that looks like the below when stripped down:

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div class="dialog">
     <!-- modal content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
</div>
```

With the following (also stripped down CSS):

```css
.dialog {
  /* full width & height (assuming mobile-only) */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, darkblue); 
}

.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

It all looks great...

[image]

*until* I focus on an input and then this happens:

[image: Weird CSS issue]

The `dialog` background is getting clipped, and I start seeing the backdrop background at the bottom.

How do I fix this (without having to change the backdrop background to match the dialog)?

**EDIT:** After some testing, I found that setting a fixed-height to the `dialog` equivalent to `window.innerHeight` before the input gets focus resolves the blank space issue. It's messy, but I hope someone has a better solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by specifying the height in `px`, as opposed to using `height: 100%`. I did this via Javascript, but waiting for DOM load and then replacing `height: 100%`.

Here's what that looked like:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    // Wait 1 sec; height isn't always correct on load for some reason
    const dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0]
    dialog.style.height = dialog.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px"
  }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your **dialog** parent has no height that is why **dialogs** `height: 100%;` doesn't work properly. try `height: -webkit-fill-available;` or give your background color to **modal** which works as a wrapper. and remove `position: absolute;` from **dialog** there is no need to use absolute here so try to make it center without it. hope it was helpful

Comment: `position: absolute` obviates the need to have a full-height/width parent. Also, this is a responsive dialog so I need the absolute there (along with offset `transforms` to ensure that it is centered properly).

Comment: I don't know man, I tried to write what you did and it worked fine. if you could share more info or code, I can help you more.